# A grammar question

Tags: exam-questions

> Living alone in a foreign country, the poor girl was quite unable to handle the stress **______** from her husband and family, especially now that she was pregnant.

> **A) having been separated
>
> B) to separating
>
> C) to be separated
>
> D) separated
>
> E) of being separated**

My answer is "D" but the answer key says its "E"

Why?

Comment: The answer is not D. But your question is too vague: what is it that you are having trouble with?

Comment: the answer key says D imo its B i dont understand how this question is D

Comment: If the answer key says D then it's wrong.

Comment: so my answer is true right ?

Comment: B is correct, or B would be correct if a space was inserted in "wouldn't be".

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Always type out the question context.

Comment: Screenshots are prohibited because this website exists for the benefit of the public. If you type your question, the words used in it can be indexed for searchability. If you take a picture of words, the words cannot be indexed, and fewer people would benefit from your question or any posted answers if they can't find the question easily.

Comment: Also when your question gets closed, please don't post it again as a new question. Pleases edit your old question, get it on-topic, and request for it to be reopened. By posting a new question you first invalidated the existing answer(s) and circumvented the close-edit-reopen mechanism and community vote that are at the core of Stack Exchange.

Comment: And in case you are wondering, your question is still off topic for lack of details and research effort. Please see this: [Detail, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by figuring out who or what is separated from who or what. Based on the context, we can assume that it is *the girl* who is separated from *her husband and family*.

What does option D say? "The girl was unable to handle the stress separated from her husband and family." Put like this, without a comma, the word "separated" does not refer to the girl, but rather to the stress; somehow, the stress got separated from the girl's relatives. I can't make sense of this, can you?

If there was a comma, though, then you'd have a descriptive clause* that refers to "the girl", but is itself separated from the subject (no pun intended). Then the meaning would be reasonable — but you don't have that comma there. In test questions, everything is important!

To conclude, let's check option E. We have: "The girl was unable to handle the stress of being separated from her husband and family." Here, the stress is caused by the separation of the girl from her family, which is totally sensible. Therefore, E is indeed the correct answer.

---

* I'm not sure if this is the correct term, but I hope that it's clear what I meant by it.

Answer (score 0):

I think none of the suggested answers is correct. I would use *didn't insist/wouldn't have been* if the visit has happened and *shouldn't insist/wouldn't be* if the visit is planned for the future.

That said, given these choices, B is closest to correct. Ray didn't insist when he made the invitation (in the past) but the visit hasn't yet happened.

In any case the "so" is wrong. You just plain would have been (or would be) uncomfortable.

Comment: _So_ is fine, if informal.

Answer (score 0):

The expression **the stress of** is commonly used in English before all kinds of stressful situations. If these situations are lasting or permanent, people will talk about **the stress of being poor** rather than just **the stress of poverty**.

Similarly:

> the stress of being ill
> the stress of being bullied
> the stress of being abused
> and so on.

In your case, what the girl is unable to cope with is **the stress of being separated from her family**.

The choice of **D** might be possible if there was a comma after **stress**. That's to say: **She was unable to handle the stress, separated from her family.....**, which is another way of saying **being separated from her family**.

As it stands, however, **E** is correct.